# XSLT | How to fetch 3 nodes with the most frequently values of the child node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to get top 3 the most popular values from below XML. I think it's not so hard, but I don't have any idea for XPath. If it could be done by single XPath expression, it'll be enough for me.

`sample.xml`:

```
<values>
    <node id="1">
        <value>5</value>
    </node>
    <node id="2">
        <value>4</value>
    </node>
    <!--AND SO ON-->
```

I want to display in output IDs of 3 nodes

Comment: You could use `for-each ` and `sort` on the `value` column in descending order. Then during the iteration use `position()` and test against 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: I think it will check the greatest 3 values, instead of 3 the most frequently used.

Comment: A string between in `<value>[here]</value>`. For example: '5' appeared 3 times, '1' 6 times, '7' 1 time, than output should be: '1, 5, 7'

Comment: If you can have several `value` elements with the same number and you want to group them by the number and sort the groups by the number of items in each group then use a standard grouping and sorting e.g. `<xsl:for-each-group select="values/node/value" group-by="."><xsl:sort select="count(current-group())" order="descending"/><xsl:if test="position() lt 3"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:if></xsl:for-each-group>`. I am not sure whether you want to count or output `value` element values or `node` `id`s.